How to assign roles to Keycloak created uses in Datahub?
I am trying to create users and groups via Keycloak which works for me perfectly following the tutorial on: https://www.syscrest.com/2022/11/datahub-oidc-identity-group-managment-with-keycloak/
The groups and the users on it are created on Datahub. Admin roles are not assigned to them as I wished it would be.
When the user is created it does not have a role assigned to it, I wished that I could set this via OPA/OPAL/Keycloak itself.
Is there any way to manage these policies?
